Segmentation Fault (core dumped) with SIGSEGV in Gaussrate
I'm a chemist using a computational chemistry software called Gaussrate, and I'm encountering a segmentation fault that I don't know how to resolve. I have very limited knowledge of programming or debugging, so I'm seeking guidance on how to diagnose and fix this issue. Below is the error message and backtrace that I received:
Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x149091fee171 in ???
#1  0x149091fed313 in ???
#2  0x14909125db4f in ???
#3  0x4c9b9a in ???
#4  0x4d9860 in ???
#5  0x4f8827 in ???
#6  0x50692d in ???
#7  0x506ac1 in ???
#8  0x149091249d84 in ???
#9  0x401a7d in ???
#10  0xffffffffffffffff in ???
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Details:
Operating System: Running on a Linux environment
Context: The segmentation fault occurs during the execution of a scientific computation in Gaussrate.
Questions:

As a chemist with no programming experience, what tools or methods can I use to understand where the segmentation fault is occurring?

Based on the backtrace, what could be the likely causes of this segmentation fault? Are there common issues related to invalid memory references that I should check?

Any general advice on how to handle and debug segmentation faults on Linux, especially for someone without a programming background, would be greatly appreciated.


Thank you in advance for your help!

"Segmentation fault" is the Unix/Linux way of saying "Illegal Memory Access". Your program tried to access an out-of-bounds memory address. Experience suggests location 0x00.
The rest of the message "(core dumped)" is good news! A long, detailed report has been written to a file in the /var/crash/ directory. Read it with less or more.
Are you missing a library? That could cause a jump to 0x00. Look at ldd $(type -p Gaussrate).

As I mentioned elsewhere, a missing library in the list of libraries shown by ldd won’t cause a segfault, it will prevent the program from starting entirely. On top of that, core dumps aren’t readable with less or more; they’re readable with a debugger. Read man 5 core.


As a chemist with no programming experience, what tools or methods can I use to understand where the segmentation fault is occurring?

This is true for both programmers and non-programmers: the most important tool here is a connection to the supplier or community of the software that's crashing.
Your first step would usually be figuring out how you got into possession of the software. Often with scientific software, you had to compile it yourself (or your colleague did). If it crashes, are you sure you didn't change your system since you compiled it? Just copying the compiled software from one system to another generally does not work (exceptions exist).
If you got this software from some binary package for your Linux distro, then check whether it is really meant for your version of that distro (and not for some other version), and maybe whether you can get the debug symbols package for that same distro package. Sorry for being vague here, I just have no idea what you're working on! "Linux" really isn't specific enough here.
So, if you can ask the person that compiled that software for you, or you compiled it yourself, the first step here would be to compile it again, but this time including debugging symbols. That way, your error information would get much more precise: you'd see something like #1 <memory address> in do_density_estimate(int molecular_weight=-28888819) instead of #1  0x149091fed313 in ???.
You'd honestly, without learning the programming language of the program in question yourself, probably still not know how to fix that – but it would make it much easier to search for solutions online, or communicate with others about the problem.

Based on the backtrace, what could be the likely causes of this segmentation fault? Are there common issues related to invalid memory references that I should check?

As waltinator said, something tried to access memory that it's not allowed to access. In my experience, that's rarely address 0 (most programming environments get rather clever about dealing with that one specific address), but even if we know the exact address, it gives us no indications whatsoever. Address space layouts, and hence addresses of running programs, are random. Hence above recommendation to get debug symbols.

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Yeah, it says that. Often it lies, because core dumping and the saving of core dumps to disk are restricted (for good reason) on modern end-user Linux systems. You can check with coredumpctl whether there's a "present" in the COREFILE column of the last entry.

Any general advice on how to handle and debug segmentation faults on Linux, especially for someone without a programming background, would be greatly appreciated.

First of all, assure yourself that this isn't your fault. These things can be extremely frustrating – even for the most experienced programmers.
Secondly, and most importantly, make sure you have a sane installation. That is, in my humble experience of both being a software developer and maintainer, as well as doing software customer support, the nr. 1 reason: Users install software in wildly unrecommended ways. Make sure you really have it installed in the right way. It needs a specific version of two other pieces of software – POLYRATE and Gaussian. You need to have installed them before you build gaussrate.
Then, make sure the executable you're running was meant for your system. Then, check whether example data can be processed. Then, write down as detailed a description of what you did, include the input data, include the core dump (coredumpctl -o crash.coredump dump -1), include how you saved the core dump, and send an email to the user community.
The "user community" for niche scientific software might simply not exist. Or it might just be the person who wrote the original program, and they might simply not have time to help you (they'd be doing that for free, so be nice and patient). Still, many projects do have mailing lists, and you're usually very welcome to subscribe to these and write a question there!
I'll say that when I looked into the contents of gaussrate17-B.tar.xz before writing this answer, I had a very strong moment of "oh dear, this is classical scientist's software". Most scientist (and especially computer scientists) are not experts in developing software that is easy to install. In this case, that means that everything about how they compile the software is self-built, and thus non-standard. In basically all other software, a configure script follows a standard pattern, and isn't some hand-written PERL routine :) Since you're one of the users of that routine, you might have to change it; sorry. They do stupid things to their build program (they modify the Makefile when building, so make gets very confused), which only happens to people not experienced with packaging software – which is understandable: this is really, really old computer scientists' and computational chemistry software, not software written by a professional software developer!
For example, to get debug symbols into the build (which as described above seems very desirable), you need to fix the point where $(F77C) or $(MPIF77C) are used in configure; I'd go in and replace $(F77C) with $(F77C) $(FFLAGS) and $(MPIF77C) with $(MPIF77C) $(FFLAGS), before I do export FFLAGS=-g before I do the steps described in the GAUSSRATEQuickstartGuide.pdf.
